# multiple enemies in the array are affected during collision

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

```
    private function enemyCollisionGoblin():void 
    {


        var goblinCanMove:Boolean = true;;

        for (var i:int = 0; i < aGoblinArray.length; i++)
        {
            var goblin:Goblin = aGoblinArray[i];
            //goblin hits player
            if (goblin.hitTestPoint(_character.x + 30, _character.y - 45, true) || goblin.hitTestPoint(_character.x - 30, _character.y - 45, true))
            {
                if (!defendKey)
                {
                    currentHP -= 1;
                    updateHealthBar();  
                    chckDeathCon();
                }
                goblinCanMove = false; 
                goblin.canAttack();
            }

            if (attackKey && lookingLeft &&!lookingRight)
            {
                if (goblin.hitTestPoint(_character.x + 100, _character.y - 45, true))
                {
                    goblinCanMove = false; 
                    trace("lance hits");
                    //hitOnce
                    if (!hitOnce)
                    {
                        hitOnce = true;
                        goblin.moveBack();
                        trace("take on damage");
                    }
                }
            }

            if (goblinCanMove)
            {

                goblin.canMove();

            }
        }
    }

           //this is before this happens, declared on top of main constructor 
           private var aGoblinArray = new Array(container.goblin1, container.goblin2, container.goblin3);
```

hello programmers, I have a problem with arrays and logic.

what I have done is looped through the array to make sure that the three enemies, the goblins are in the loop.

After I have data typed a variable called goblin to the Goblin  class and that equals the goblin array and the variable i which equals 1, 2 and 3 which are the goblins that are in the array.

if the goblin hits the enemy, then the goblin can attack and goblinCanMove = false;
This means that the goblin in the array, that hits the enemy should not move and should attack.

But the problem is that when the first enemy hits the goblin, (goblin1) this goblin stops moving and attacks whilst goblin1 and goblin2 move. But when the goblin2 hits the enemy, goblin2 does stop and attack. But goblin1 and goblin3 stop moving.

When goblin3 attacks the enemy it stops and attacks, althouh goblin1 stops moving, however goblin2 does move with out hesitation.

Same thing applies for the attack, when i attack goblin1, he stops moving and goblin2 and 3 move.

I attack goblin2, all goblins are affected. I attack goblin3, he stops and so does goblin1.

Here is the goblin class.

```
    package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import Main;
import player;

/**
 * ...
 * @author Moynul Hussain
 */
public class Goblin extends MovieClip {
    private var nTimer: Number;
    private var goblinLife; int;
    public static var lookingRight: Boolean;
    public static var canAttackLeft: Boolean;
    public static var canAttackRight: Boolean;

    public var attack: Boolean;
    public var speed: int;
    public static var move: Boolean;

    public function Goblin() {
        move = true;
        nTimer = 0;
        speed = 1;
        goblinLife = 2;
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdd)

    }


    private function onAdd(e: Event): void {
        //trace("added Goblin");
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdd);
        //this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, goblinLoop);
    }

    public function goblinLoop():void
    {

    }

    public function canAttack():void 
    {
        this.gotoAndStop("attack");

    }

    public function canMove(): void 
    {
        nTimer = nTimer + 0.05;
        if (nTimer < 5) 
        {
            lookingRight = false;
            this.scaleX = -1;
            this.gotoAndStop("run");
            this.x += speed;
            lookingRight = true;
            //trace("right");
        } 
        else 
        {
            lookingRight = false;
        //trace("looking LEFT");
            this.x -= speed;
            this.gotoAndStop("run");
            this.scaleX = 1;
            if (nTimer > 10) //this can't be 5, it's not logical, so it has to be 10)
            {
                nTimer = 0;
            }
        }
    }



    public function moveRight():void 
    {
            this.x -= speed;
            this.gotoAndStop("run");
            this.scaleX = 1;    
    }

    public function rangeAttack():void 
    {


    }

    public function takeDamage():void 
    {
        goblinLife--;
    }

    public function doNothing():void 
    {
        this.gotoAndStop(1);
    }

    public function moveBack():void 
    {
        this.gotoAndStop("beenHit");
        this.x
    }





}
```

}

Sorry if it's a lot to take in.

Comment: So much goblin.  What's your question?

Comment: Oops, forgot the question.

the question is how can I make sure that the other goblins in the array are no affected. 

For e.g. goblin2 hits me it will stop walking and hit me. But, goblin1 and goblin3 will stop moving too. But they won't attack. They'll stop moving. 

How can I stop this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your boolean is initially set to true, but as soon as one golblin sets it to false, it becomes false for all the goblins. Try moving it into the for loop instead:

```
private function enemyCollisionGoblin():void 
{
    var goblinCanMove:Boolean;
    for (var i:int = 0; i < aGoblinArray.length; i++)
    {
        goblinCanMove = true;
        /* rest of the code */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, what I've done is promoted that variable and intiated it in the main constructor function. The goblin can move if it's not hitting the player. 

I guess what goes around, comes around! Karma sure did help me ;D